# Enlive and tags in arbitrary places

Tags: clojure, enlive

Here's the thing with `enlive 1.1.5` (source formatting/whitespace changes added for clarity.):

```
blogen.core> (html/sniptest "<html><head>
                                <title><span id=\"foo\"/></title>
                              </head></html>"
                            [:#foo] (html/substitute "f"))
"<html><head><title></title></head></html>f"

blogen.core> (html/sniptest "<html><head>
                                <title><span id=\"foo\"/></title>
                              </head></html>"
                            [:#foo] (constantly "f"))
"<html><head><title></title></head></html>f"
```

I want to write a constant prefix in the HTML sources so that my clojure code doesn't saturate from my end content. But as the sniptest above shows, I can't have `span` tags inside `title`. The second test using core function `constantly` shows that any more custom-written transformation is not likely to succeed any better.

I wouldn't like to use the `${vars}` because they look stupid in the templates. I prefer to write decent examples in the templates that enlive can then substitute without damage.

### Motivation

I would enjoy writing the templates as HTML and use `span` elements with defined `id`'s as variable placeholders, basically. But enlive doesn't parse those `span` tags inside `title`'s as desired. To keep things less complected. Examples:

```
<title><span id="article-name"/> - <span id="my-site" /></title>
```

or

```
<p>Welcome, <span id="visitor-ip" /></p>
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "write a constant prefix in the HTML sources so that my clojure code doesn't saturate from my end content"?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to do, can't you set the `title`'s content instead with `(... "..." [:title] (html/content "f"))`?

Comment: @DanielNeal: for instance, a site title that stays the same on every page, plus a dynamic portion generated via clojure, that would replace the span element altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element), the `<title>` tag's ContentModel is Text, which means that HTML elements are not allowed within it.

The part of Enlive that parses the HTML can probably only handle valid HTML, so it won't play nicely with the `<span>` tag inside the `<title>` tag.

You've got a few options.

It is possible to just set the content of the `<title>` tag rather than substituting it completely, like this:

```
(html/sniptest "<html><head><title>Placeholder</title></head></html>"
               [:title] (html/content "foo"))

;; => <title>foo</title>
```

Or if you want to keep a part of the title constant, you could use `append` or `prepend`

```
(html/sniptest "<html><head><title>Some Title</title></head></html>"
                [:title] (html/append " - sub page"))

;; => <title>Some Title - sub page</title>
```

**EDIT**

I know that you said you want to avoid `${vars}`, but in this case, they happen to do exactly what you're looking for...

```
(html/sniptest "<html><head><title>${my-site} - ${article-name}</title></head></html>"
               [:title] (html/transform-content
                          (html/replace-vars
                             {:article-name "Using Enlive for good and evil"
                              :my-site "Clojure Weekly"})))

;; =>  <title>Clojure Weekly - Using Enlive for good and evil</title>
```

Comment: Very good. Once I understood the spec defines title contents as text nodes, it made sense that enlive doesn't parse it. Plus I like the `append` transformer, which is *good enough* :)